# Allocate memory space larger than SIZE_T/UINT dynamically (i.e. on the heap)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, memory-management, heap-memory

I have a requirement to allocate a block of contiguous memory space of size only storable in a `LONGLONG (long long)` container. A warning of type [`C4244`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-2-c4244?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C4244)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019) is thrown by the compiler when a `LONGLONG` value is used with the `new` statement or `malloc()` function, stating that there is a possible loss of data when converting from `LONGLONG` to `size_t` (in the case of `malloc()`) or `unsigned int` (in the case of `new`).

I am using the Visual C++ compiler.

Thanks in advance.

```
LONGLONG allocSize;
PBYTE memPool;
 
memPool = new BYTE[allocSize]; // C4244
memPool = (PBYTE) malloc(allocSize); // C4244
```

Comment: this can not be if you compile as 64-bit. i guess you compile code as 32-bit

Comment: *and building for/on a 64-bit system* on which system you build not play any role, *build for 64-bit os* yet not mean that your code 64-bit. compiler warning clear say that you code is 32-bit. in this case you anyway can not allocate more that 4gb. in any case you can not allocate more that *size_t*

Comment: You are using a C++ compiler. This is C++ code that can't be compiled with a C compiler. Why do you insist to tag this question with C?

Comment: *I have a requirement to allocate a block of contiguous memory space of size only storable in a `LONGLONG (long long)` container.*  That seems likely to be a nonsensical requirement.  Systems where objects can be of a size too large to fit into a `size_t` are pretty rare.

Comment: @hecate How do you plan on dynamically allocating an object larger than `size_t` in C?  You ***can't*** use `malloc()` because its argument is of type `size_t`.  Whoever devised your requirement to use an `[unsigned] long long` for an object size needs to both learn C and also stop putting implementation details into requirements.

Comment: @ThomasSablik how do you know what compile he is using??

Comment: @YunfeiChen OP wrote it in an earlier version of the question.  Also you can find out. C4244 is a MSVC warning ID. There is no `new` in C. So it has to be MSVC++

Comment: Do you memorize what warning ID's belong to which system or something??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stated warning only persisted as the code was set to compile to the x86 instruction set, in which no more than 4 GB of memory can be used. As in any (and every) case/instance, it is impossible to allocate contiguous memory beyond the range of `SIZE_T` which makes the range of the size datatype of the x64 architecture wider than that of the x86 (32-bit) architecture.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
LONGLONG allocSize;
PBYTE memPool;

int nAllocSize = (int) allocSize;  // cast to an integer
 
memPool = new BYTE[nAllocSize]; // no more C4244

memPool = (PBYTE) malloc(nAallocSize); // no more C4244
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers.